# Best way to update an object that's referencing data from another object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm having trouble thinking of the best way to go about this without a framework.  Let's say I have code that looks like this.

```
let x = {
    someData: 5
}

let config = [{
   moreData: `You have ${x.someData} flunderflaffles`
}]
//user input affects x
button.onclick = ()=>{
    x.someData++
    appendEle()
}

const appendEle = () => {
    document.body.append(`<p>${config.moreData}</p>`)
}
```

This is a very simple explanation of what I'm doing right now but I hope you get the gist.  Basically config.moreData will always have a value of 5 since thats what it was when it was initialized.  Can anyone shed some light on how to handle this better so that the data in config reflects that in x? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to handle better?

Comment: A simple approach: Instead of a string, `moreData` could be a function that doesn't expect any arguments like `moreData: () => \`You have ${x.someData} flunderflaffles\``

Comment: Use a function that returns a dynamically created object instead. `function config() { return { moreData: \`You have ${x.someData} flunderflaffles\` } }` Now use `config().moreData` instead (or, yes, make `moreData` a function instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure that the string is created dynamically, when you need it. For that you need a function. A [getter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) enables the API to remain the same:

```js
const config = {
   get moreData() { return `You have ${x.someData} flunderflaffles` }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const moreData = config.moreData
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Remember to use getter properties sparingly because they are usually unexpected by other developers.